# Previous values being overwritten each time a new on is added in a linked list

Tags: java, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to add objects of my original class "day" that have integer values called "classment" to a linked list so I can keep track of which day comes first. The problem is, each time I add a day to this linked list and change the value of it's 'classment' to it's ranking in the list, all the previously added days also change the value of their 'classment' to the last one added. here's a simplification of the code

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        LinkedList <day> days = new LinkedList<day>(); 
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            day dayx = new day(); // Create a new day object here
            dayx.classment = i;
            days.add(dayx);
            dayx = null;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.err.println(days.get(i).classment);
        }
    }
```

the result is just

```
4
4
4
4
4
```

I know this seems like a very simple problem that has many solutions online already, but all the results I found were in C++, and I couldn't translate the solution to java. It might even be me not fully understanding the concept of linked lists, but I did try regular arrays and I ended up with the same problem.

I just need them to be separate days with their separate variables and values. I want the result to simply be:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

this is also a simplification of what the day class looks like:

```
public class day {

    static Double startingRest=0.0, currentRest=0.0;
    static int rownumber=-1,N=0;
    static String date,title;
    static int classment;

    public day(){
        rownumber=-1;
        N=0;
        startingRest=0.0;
        currentRest=0.0;
    }

}
```

Comment: my guess it's an issue in your day class. Can you post that code? You should follow naming conventions, that would make the code easier tor ead. Also, making all the member of that class 'public' is probably not the best idea

Comment: I didn't think it mattered because it's just a simple 'int classment;', but I'll add the day class for clarification. also it being public is just for simplification.

Comment: Is `classment` by chance `static`? The code works if it is instance variable, but would print only 4s, if it is class variable (static).

Comment: Seems unrelated to linked list. You'd have the same behaviour if you would just create two `day` objects and assign different values to their `classment` fields. I don't see why `pointers` would be a relevant tag here either (read the usage description).

Comment: @SmolCheetah just assumes it matters. Always post sufficient code to allow us to reproduce the issue

Comment: 'classment' is static yes... it being static is a problem? i only made it static cause the code wouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: @SmolCheetah Making the classment field static in your Day class causes it to be shared among all instances of the Day class. This means that every Day object you create will have the same classment value, which is not what you want for your scenario.

Comment: @Feelfree THAT DID THE JOB. I didn't know what static actually meant... I feel stupid.

Comment: if your goal is to have for each instance to have a classment that is previous+1, you can perfectly do that within the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `classment` as a static field of `day`. That means only one copy of it is shared between all instances of the class. Each time you set a different value of any `day.classment` it changes it for all instances of day.

Just remove the `static` keyword from `classment` and you should see different values per instance.  The same goes for the other `static` fields - make sure you really want them to be static.

Further to that, there are other modifiers you might consider to use instead of static. For example, you should decide if classment is a public or private field. If public then anyone can access it directly as in `day.classment`, whereas if it's private you should provide a getter and setter (`day.getClassment()`) for it.

Comment: That worked! I realized that I didn't really know what the keyword static actually did... to be honest I don't know why I made them static in the first place, the debugging process suggested that at some point and i did it just cause it removed the errors that i had at that time.